# Formulario reactivo no devuelve valores

Tags: angular, webforms, reactiveformsmodule

Buen día, estoy tratando de crear un formulario reactivo en angular 10 pero a la hora de leer los datos, es como si el evento que asigna el valor a las variables no se ejecutara.

el punto es que aunque los campos del formulario estén llenos el objeto que arroja el formulario reactivo siempre esta vacío

Este es el componente .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formLogin: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private _builder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.formLogin = this._builder.group({
      user: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
      passwd: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(50)])]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  sendData(value: any) {
    console.log(this.formLogin.value);
  }
  onSubmitData(value: any) {
    console.log(this.formLogin.value);
  }



  /**
   * Este método no se puede modificar
   * */
  public redirectUsers(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/users/list');
  }

}
```

El html es este:

```
<div class="my-container">
  <form class="formLogin" [formGroup]="formLogin" (onSubmit) ="onSubmitData()">

    <h3 class="titleLogin">Inicio de sesión</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login__email">Correo electrónico</label>
      <input formControlName="user" type="email" name="login__email" id="login__email">
    </div>
    <!-- <div *ngif="formLogin.get('email').hasError('email') && formLogin.get('email').touched">
      <span id="login__email-error">Error email</span>
    </div> -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login__password">Contraseña</label>
      <input formControlName="passwd" type="password" name="login__password" id="login__password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn-login" id="login__btn-login" [disabled]="!formLogin.invalid" type="button"
      (click)="sendData(formLogin.value)">Iniciar sesión</button>
    <h1>{{formLogin.valid}}</h1>
  </form>
</div>
```

Este es el resultado en consola [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque el formulario esta así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la atención prestada

Comment: Por que tienes dos operaciones? `sendData` y `onSubmit`?

Comment: eso fue porque estaba probando el ngSubmit y tampoco funciono